# Laravel 5.7 , login redirectes back to login

Tags: laravel-5.7, laravel-authentication

Im using laravel 5.7, I implemented login using make-auth().
also folowing is my login funtion:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|unique:users|max:255',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials= ['email' => $request->get('email'), 'password'=>$request->get('password')];

    if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials)) {
      $user = Auth::user();
      return redirect(route('home'));
    }

    $validator->errors()->add('login', 'Invalid Credentials');
    return redirect()->back()
        ->with('loginError','Invalid Credentials')
        ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}
```

When I try login, the page get redirected back to the login page.
Am I missing out something or is there anything to be added in middleware or any other file

Comment: Perhaps going through the [documentation on authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication) shall help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this part might be the issue?

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => 'required|unique:users|max:255',
    'password' => 'required',
]);
```

By adding a `unique` validation rule to the *login* page (as opposed to the *registration* page), an existing user would be redirected back with a validation error every time because their email is already in the database.

Check your login page and make sure you're displaying form validation errors. If you see an error stating that the email must be unique, then this is the cause.

Here's a snippet you can use to display errors (from https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)

```html
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```